# Do I need to restart windows server after Installing .Net Framework 4.7.1

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, .net-framework-version

What I learned from windows 7 machine is that when I install .Net Framework 4.7.1 it requires reboot to take effect, otherwise the application designed with this .Net fx version is not able to launch.

So, do I also need to reboot if I install .Net fx 4.7.1 on Windows server edition(2008r2 onwards)?

I want to automate this piece of installing .Net fx and app through one script, so I have achieved script piece but not sure about rebooting windows server

If I do want to reboot windows server then can this be added as a part of my power shell based script?

EDIT my sample script is as below

```
if(Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'){
$NetRegKey = Get-Childitem %%'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
if($NetRegKey){
    $Release = $NetRegKey.GetValue("Release")
    if($Release){
        if($Release -lt 461308){
            try{
                $prc = Start-Process C:\NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe -Wait
            }
            catch{

            }
        }
    }       
    }
}
else{
try{
    $prc = Start-Process C:\NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe -Wait
}
catch{

}
}
```

Comment: It would help if we could see your current code. How are you installing the framework?

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: @MrTux I do not have access to win server machine, hence I could not gave a try

Comment: @I.TDelinquent, added my script code

Comment: There are numerous scripts floating online that explicitly test if a reboot is required; I suggest you use those and reboot if they indicate it's necessary. It is not the case that the installation will always or never require a reboot; that will also dependent on what was already installed on the server. (In fact, if you're unlucky installation can fail *because* a reboot is required first, so testing for that may be worthwhile regardless.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my own question above is

```
if( -NOT ((Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\SKUs\.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1') -or (Test-Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe') -or (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'))) {

Start-Process .\DotNetFX471\NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe -RedirectStandardError "DotNetInstallationStatus.txt" -Wait
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0){
    Write-Host "ERROR: "
    Get-Content -Path .\appInstallStatus.txt
    return
}
Write-Host ".Net Framework installation is completed successfully"
}

Write-Host "Running CIE installer, please wait..."

$installerParam = "--p 'C:\Program Files\APP'"
Start-Process .\install.exe $installerParam -RedirectStandardError "appInstallStatus.txt" -Wait

if ($LastExitCode -ne 0){
    Write-Host "ERROR: "
    Get-Content -Path .\appInstallStatus.txt
    return
}
```

Once we install .Net framework on any windows server we should see folder created at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" run this MSBuild.exe to get version. 
Normally if we do not have .Net framework then this folder won't be available, though if this folder available then you will get correct .Net framework version by running this MSBuild.exe file.